# How can I import a Site Collection to another host?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, sitecollection

I am trying to export the content from a staging server and import it into a development machine. I've tried to do this with `Backup-SPSite -Identity http://staging -Path c:/export.bin` on staging  and `Restore-SPSite -Identity http://devmachine -Path c:/export.bin -Force` on development, but after I do this, some assets (e.g. images in webparts) still point to the staging server. Is there some *secret sauce* that I'm unaware of?

I've tried to use the `-HostHeader` switch, but was unable to restore the backup when it was specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be my own mistake - my web parts were saving absolute urls instead of relative.